# Sum of the total numbers of the number added in between them

Tags: number-theory, summation

Here's the question that I was instructed to do:

**Write numbers 2, 2 on your paper.   Write the sum of two numbers between them.  We get 2,  4,  2.  Repeat:  2,  6,  4,  6,  2.  Repeat:  2, 8, 6, 10, 4, 10, 6, 8, 2.  Find the sum of all numbers on the paper after repeating this 2017 times.**

I tried using arithmetic and geometric progression, but to no avail, I can't find any sequence that would define them. (The sum is 4, 8, 20, 56, 164,... for the first, second, third and so on.) I have also tried using the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  you should be looking for a recurrence relation among the sums.  If you have a middle number in the $n^{th}$ sum how many times does it contribute to the $(n+1)^{st}$ sum?  How about the end $2$s?

Added much later:  the end $2$s of one row are counted two times in the next, once at the outer $2$ and once in the sum one inboard.  Every other entry in a row gets counted three times in the next row, once in its place and once in the sum on each side.  If $a_n$ is the sum of the $n^{th}$ row, the recurrence is $a_{n+1}=3a_n-4$ because there are two $2$s that are only counted twice.  By the usual technique for inhomogeneous linear recurrence relations, the solution is $a_n=b3^n+2$.  If the first $2\ 2$ row is row $0$ this says $b=2$ and $a_n=2\cdot 3^n+2$, which matches your series.

Comment: should i divide it into two parts? like for the left side and the right side, and in the end total it up? sorry i still can't see how it works

Comment: When you go from the second line to the third, the $4$ in the middle gets counted three times in the sum, once in the middle $4$ and once in each of the $6$s.  When you go from the third to the fourth, the $4$ in the middle gets counted ???  The $6$s next to it get counted ???